# How to change the xml within the same activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I´m trying to change xml layouts (the differences are mainly the distribution of the components inside) within the same activity. Actually is a pitch (background of the layouts) and have different formations (distribution of the elements) in each xml (with linearlayouts). The idea is to have a button in the screen which allows me to change the formation (switch to another xml). 
Also I would like to go to a different activity when user will click a player, but that´s a different history I think.

Any idea about how to switch to different xml layout?

Thanks!

Comment: Try just calling `setContentView()` with the new XML.

Comment: Call setContentView() on each button click and pass layouts of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

To switch layouts (xml file) you can use this line of code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layoutiwanttoswitchto);
```

However, you should take a look at **fragments**, maybe its more what you need

To start new activity do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityYouWantToStart.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks for your answer, but I think it is not the best option, as I read somewhere else is not recommended doing setContentView that often.

Comment: any link with Fragment tutorial and where is explained how to apply what I´m asking for?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is Just take a main layout as Linear Layout. setContentView to that layout.Create different xml for the layouts you want to show on click of button. On click of button just inflate the layouts accordingly on condition with LayoutInflater and add it to the main Linear LAyout.

For eg

```
 onCreate{
   setcontentView(R.layout.main);
   LinearLayout linear= findViewbyId(R.id.mainLinear)
 }
 OnFirstButtonClick(){
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first);
   linear.removeAllViews();
   linear.addView(v);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use thread class and set time limit for xml layout and for button event use Intent i think this will work.

Comment: I do not understand your answer, I want to change layout based on user ´s decision (when user selects a different formation), not on time limit. This is one thing, and another is that actually I´m asking about how to do it, no when.